# Undefined offset error in for loop

Tags: php, encryption

This code helps me find the minimum of certain sums, so I set a function as the one below:

```
 function GetMin($s)
    {

        for($j=1;$j<=count($s)-1;$j++)
        {
            $min=$s[1];
            if($s[$j] < $s[$j+1] && $s[$j] < $min)
            {
                $min=$s[$j];
            }
    else {continue;}        
        }
        echo $min;
    }

$enc=".129.25.24.154.546.214.142.254.256";
$ar=explode(".",$enc);
for($i=0;$i<count($ar)-1;$i+=3)
{
    $s[$i+1]=$ar[$i+1]+$ar[$i+2]+$ar[$i+3];
    echo $s[$i+1]."<br>";
}


GetMin($s)
```

The code should work this way:

Calculates the sum of every 3 terms of the array and store it in a term of another array called "s", the code is working well, until I try to find the minimum, it prints the minimum but with the error below:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\decrypt.php on line 9 Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\decrypt.php on line 9 Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\decrypt.php on line 9 178

Comment: why not use `foreach` and have it handle the indexing?

Comment: i doubt about your logic, please chek that once and come back if required..

Comment: @iam-decoder : I can't use `foreach` because i'm supposed to compare to the $min , and the next term of the array.
@NiranjanNRaju : I can't get what's wrong with the "logic" can you explain what do you EXACTLY mean.

Comment: your problem is that your `for()` loop prior to calling get min is creating an array with non-consecutive keys. give me few minutes and I'll post your solution

Comment: Thank you , i got it here it's about the increment +3 , i forgot about it while create the `$s`array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to get the lowest value in an array of values, so I've changed your `GetMin()` function to work with the non-consecutively indexed array that you create prior to calling `GetMin()`. This should work for you:

```
<?php
function GetMin($s){
    $min = NULL;
    foreach($s as $v){
        if(is_null($min)){
            $min = $v;
        } elseif($v < $min){
            $min = $v;
        }
    }
    return $min;
}
$enc = ".129.25.24.154.546.214.142.254.256";
$ar = explode(".",$enc);
$ar_count = count($ar);
for($i=0;$i<$ar_count-1;$i+=3)
{
    $s[$i+1]=$ar[$i+1]+$ar[$i+2]+$ar[$i+3];
    echo $s[$i+1]."<br>";
}


echo GetMin($s);
```